# Calculating relative point coordinates for a graph?

Tags: javascript, graph

I'm making a simple *JavaScript* graphing library using the canvas element. I really suck at math so I'm stuck with a simple issue.

If I have a number - for example **30000**, and I want to plot it relatively to graph's height which is **400**. How do I calculate the y value for that?

Comment: What's the limit? I mean, what would the top Y value be? 100,000?

Comment: In graph terms - 400. In data terms - unlimited.

Comment: If there is no limit in terms of data then it will have to be bound by the highest Y point in whatever data you're plotting. So, if 30,000 happens to be the highest data item then its height on the graph would be 100% => i.e. 400px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to figure out your max for the graph. Say, in this case 50000. Then, take your height and divide it by the max (so 400/50000) to get a ratio multiplier. Any number you want to plot you multiply by that ratio and that should give you a number that fits on your space. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: There is no limit in terms of data.

Comment: But you have to figure out how high your chart is, right? It's going to be a lot of scrolling down if your top number in the chart is infinity. :)  For that, you can figure out your max data point and then just give the chart a bit of a buffer. So, if the highest Y you have to chart at the moment is 30000, make your top point 40000.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to first find out the maximum and minimum values that you need to plot. For example, in this list of `(x,y)` coordinates: `[(1,3),(2,10),(3,0),(4,-10)]`, the max value is 10 and the min value is -10. This gives you a span of `(max-min = 10-(-10) = )` 20.

Notice that you can now translate the set of y values into a number in the range `[0,max-min]` (i.e. `[0,20]` in this case). Here, a value of 0 will get plotted as a 0 in the graph and a value of 20 will get plotted as 400. Also, a value of `20/2` will be plotted as `400/2`. Thus, a value of `20/x` is plotted as `400/x`. This means that any value can now be plotted as 400*value/20.

So, to translate a given value `n` to its corresponding y value on the graph, simply convert `n` to `(n-min)*400/(max-min)`.